# How to code for a variable in the Kivy label?

Tags: kivy, python-3.7

I'm trying to create a simple Kivy function that counts and updates the display in the label as either a variable or a variable that has been converted to string. Using Python 3.7 and Kivy 1.10.1

I've been reading previous questions related to labels, but they don't seem to fix my issue. Thanks.

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
import time

class SomeData():
    num = 0
    while num < 1000:
        time.sleep(1)
        num+=1

class FirstScreen (Screen):

    runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
ScreenManager:
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen> 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            spacing: '10dp'
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: "Below is a scroll of numbers."

        ScrollView:
            Label:
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                text: (num)
    '''))
```

The file never creates the Kivy screen and num variable is considered an error in the text label.

Comment: You need a class that extends `App`. See [https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#creating-an-application].

Comment: Also, you are creating a root widget `ScreenManager` in your `kv` sting, but you are not using it. Also, there is no way for Kivy to determine where the `num` variable in your `kv` string comes from. If you define `num` in your `FirstScreen` class (as an instance variable), then you can reference it as `str(root.num)` in your `kv`.

Comment: I missed the fact that you are calling `runTouchApp`.  That call should not be indented, and you should add a `pass` statement to complete your `FirstScreen` declaration. Your `SomeData` class will run its loop as soon as it  is loaded, so your display will not appear until that loop is completed (at least 1000 seconds).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version for your code that will, at least, display:

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
#import time

# class SomeData:
#     num = 0
#     while num < 1000:
#         time.sleep(1)
#         num+=1

class FirstScreen (Screen):
    num = NumericProperty(7)

runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('''
ScreenManager:
    FirstScreen:

<FirstScreen> 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            spacing: '10dp'
            Button:
            Button:
            Button:

        Label:
            size_hint_y: None
            text: "Below is a scroll of numbers."

        ScrollView:
            Label:
                text_size: self.width, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                halign: 'left'
                valign: 'top'
                text: str(root.num)
    '''))
```

The `SomeData` class is commented out, since it does nothing but delay the display. Also, note that changing the value of `num` in a loop will not create a list of numbers, but will just change the number that is displayed in the `Label`. There is no need to import the time too. So, commented it.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I was using the while loop to simulate a number that would keep updating. Thank you.